# Why do Aura-Creatures Immediately Die?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I found the below ruling for [Encroaching Mycosynth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Encroaching%20Mycosynth):

> Encroaching Mycosynth's ability causes Auras to become artifacts. This makes it more likely that another effect (such as that of March of the Machines) will make those artifact Auras into creatures. An Aura that's also a creature can't enchant anything. **It's unattached the next time state-based actions are checked, and then immediately put into its owner's graveyard as a second state-based action**

Why is it put into its owner's graveyard? If it were because it's a creature with zero toughness I would understand that, but [March of the Machines](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=March%20of%20the%20Machines) would give it power/toughness equal to its Mana Value.

Comment: murgatroid99 has the proper rules citation, but from a philosophical perspective, "auras" are an enchantment subtype that, by their nature, *must* be attached to something (they pre-date equipment, which can happily exist whether attached or not). So if you wanted an aura enchantment to remain on the battlefield without being attached to anything, you'd have to figure out how to *remove* the aura subtype. I'm not aware of anything that could do that (without removing the enchantment type entirely).

Comment: FYI the Legends card "Takklemaggot" is the only card I could find that can make an aura become a non-aura enchantment (and it can only do it to itself), although the keyword "aura" did not exist at the time. This is one of those confusing early cards, but the oracle wording is at least slightly more understandable.

Comment: A bestowed aura will also work differently here. As soon as it becomes unattached, it stops being bestowed, which means that it stops being an aura.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a consequence of [rules 704.5m and p](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/State-based_action):

> **704.5m** If an Aura is attached to an illegal object or player, or is not attached to an object or player, that Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard.
>
> **704.5p** If a battle or creature is attached to an object or player, it becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield. Similarly, if any nonbattle, noncreature permanent that’s neither an Aura, an Equipment, nor a Fortification is attached to an object or player, it becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield.

A creature can't be attached to anything, so it falls off, and an aura dies if it is not attached to anything.