# Is it possible to have an Aura that's also a land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As part of asking [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/58802/does-equinox-take-replacement-effects-into-account), I tried to prove the first of the two scenarios was possible by inventing a combination of cards that could turn a land into an Aura. To my surprise, I was unable to do so.

This convoluted scenario was the closest I could come:

You control a [Havengul Lich](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Havengul%20Lich). Activate its ability twice and cast [Dominating Licid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dominating%20Licid) and [The Reality Chip](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Reality%20Chip) from your graveyard. Now cast, in the following order:

1. [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice) (everything is an artifact)
2. [Bludgeon Brawl](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bludgeon%20Brawl) (everything is an Equipment)
3. [March of the Machines](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=March%20of%20the%20Machines) (everything is a creature)
4. [Ashaya, Soul of the Wild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashaya%2C%20Soul%20of%20the%20Wild) (everything is a Forest land)

Then activate the ability Havengul Lich gained from Dominating Licid to turn it into an Aura and attach it to a creature. Per rule 702.151b:

> Attaching an Equipment with reconfigure to another creature causes the Equipment to stop being a creature until it becomes unattached from that creature.

But this almost certainly doesn't work, because either the continuous effects still apply and turn Havengul Lich into a creature (which will cause it to be unattached and put into its owner's graveyard), or the reconfigure rule will overwrite Ashaya's effect so that it isn't a land.

Anyway, is there a different combination of cards that can create an Aura land?

Comment: In your example/attempt, The Reality Chip and Bludgeon Brawl are redundant with Dominating Licid, because the Licid's ability already removes other types.

Comment: Also, that part doesn't even work, because Bludgeon Brawl only applies to non-creatures, and Havengul Lich is a creature. And it wouldn't work with a different card, because Bludgeon Brawl's effect has a dependency on March of the Machines' effect, so with that combination of cards, nothing would be an equipment.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Like I said, it almost certainly doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes it is!

Thanks to @murgatroid99 for mentioning Cloudform in a now-deleted answer.

I control [Vedalken Orrery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vedalken%20Orrery). I cast a [Cloudform](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudform) and it resolves. With its ETB ability on the stack, I first cast [Song of the Dryads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Song%20of%20the%20Dryads) targeting it and allow Song to resolve, holding priority. Then I cast [Enchanted Evening](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enchanted%20Evening) and let it resolve. The result is that Cloudform is an "Enchantment Land — Forest". Then its ETB ability resolves, and it becomes an "Enchantment Land — Forest Aura". We manifest the top card of our library and attach Cloudform to it.

Comment: So, lands don't have the "can't be attached" rules that creatures have?

Comment: Why is Enchanted Evening required for this?

Comment: @John _Aura_ is an _Enchantment_ subtype, and **Song of the Dryads** removes the original _Enchantment_ card type on **Cloudform**, meaning it needs to regain the _Enchantment_ card type before it becomes an _Aura_ (see rule **205.3d**)

Comment: @John You are correct; that rule is 704.5p: "If a battle or creature is attached to an object or player, it becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield. Similarly, if any nonbattle, noncreature permanent that’s neither an Aura, an Equipment, nor a Fortification is attached to an object or player, it becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield."

Answer (score 2):

You can make an Aura Land very briefly (it's about as stable as [Moscovium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscovium)).

Have the following cards on the battlefield:

- [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice)
- [March of the Machines](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=March%20of%20the%20Machines)
- [Ashaya, Soul of the Wild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashaya%2C%20Soul%20of%20the%20Wild)

Then cast any aura.  It will be an Enchantment Artifact Creature Land - Aura.  [It will then be put in the graveyard the next time state-based actions are checked](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/58798/9999) because creature's can't be attached to other objects and auras must be attached to some other object (unless it's an aura you cast with "bestow", in which case it will stop being an aura).

Comment: "It will then be put in the graveyard the next time state-based actions are checked because creature's can't be attached to other objects and auras must be attached to some other object." Unless it's one of the Bestow creatures from the Theros blocks.

Comment: @nick012000 good point